# Resize image on Windows Phone with Appcelerator

Tags: windows, appcelerator, image-resizing, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

this is my sistem

- Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit
- Appcelerator Studio 4.4.0.201511241829
- Appcelerator CLI 5.0.5
- Node.js version 4.2.4
- Titanium SDK 5.1.2
- JDK 1.8.0_66
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Windows Phone SDK 8.0/8.1
- Build target Android/Windows Phone (device/emulator)

I already made the code to get an image from Gallery and Camera using this page on the documentation [Camera and Photo Gallery APIs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Camera_and_Photo_Gallery_APIs). But now I have to upload it on my server and I need to resize the image/change the quality. On Android and iOS there is the `ti.imagefactory` on `gitTio` but is not compatible with Windows Phone.

Is there any change to get it work on Windows Phone?

In my case, I can use also the `Titanium.Blob.imageAsResized` function, as a workaround, but I can't use this function on Windows Phone. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Appcelerator does not support image resizing for uploading to server in Windows platform. You should create a new feature request ticket in https://jira.appcelerator.org/. Try to be descriptive as possible. Provide a code sample that works in Other platforms and provide information of your platform. Thanks.

Comment: I created this ticket on jira [TIMOB-20257 Manipulate images on Windows Phone](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20257). Hoping that in the future release the dev can make a ti.imagefactory compatibility also for windows phone.